# How to execute completely independent application from Java. Like independent process

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, windows-7, process

I have one main application which launch two other process's, i just need to launch them as an independent process. like running them-self without using or sharing my main application launcher process memory or cpu.

But when i launch it like this TWO other process do not get executed (well they create TWO new process but not fictional), unless i kill the main process. My plan is to execute it under windows just like THREE command prompt where it execute THREE application.

How do i resolve it so that THREE execution run completely alone?

```
/*This is Process 1 itself*/
try {

  if (myStock.getOs().equals("Linux")) 
  {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp /var/dist/test.jar main.main");        
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp /var/dist/test.jar www.webserver_starter");

  } else {

    /*Windows 7 only*/
    String WindowsTemp = System.getenv("MY") + "\\";
    /*This is Process 2*/
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp " + WindowsTemp + "dist\\test.jar main.main");        
    /*This is Process 3*/
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "java -cp " + WindowsTemp + "dist\\test.jar www.webserver_starter");
  }

} catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For *Windows* use `cmd /c start ...` where `'...'` is the command you would like to invoke.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start java -cp /var/dist/test.jar main.main")
```

For *Linux* add `&` at the end of command to start a daemon process.

Comment: You can also use ProcessBuilder which accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: @Wojtek O.: I tried the way you explained just now in Windows 7 PC. And i have the same exact issue like without `cmd /c start <whatever_Goes_here>`

Comment: It is working. `cmd /c start` is when we want to see in the task manager and also the terminal in the task bar. Without `cmd /c start` does the same job but it hides the terminal + taskbar, when someone requires to launch one central application and at the same time launch many (in my case). Both seems to be working. Thanks a lot.