# java start a new process bug

Tags: java, process, exec

I have a process that starts other processes on Linux in the same computer. It is done, like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec(nameOfProgramAndPath + parameters)
```

The above code starts the processes, but the problem is that when I stop it also the other processes stop. How do I make the other processes to be independence to the creator ?

Thanks

Comment: In Linux you can add & at the end of the command line.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8729523/4607733

Comment: Doesn't help to add &